# Vue.js clear user cache

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I'am deploying a new app version of my Vue.js SPA and got the problem that it's only loads if I clear my cache. So for me this is fine but the customers won't get it. Is there a workaround to check the version and force the browser to reload my page?
My Setup is:

- SPA created with latest Vue CLI
- Vue Bootstrap
- Bundled with Webpack
- Hosted in AWS S3 Bucket

Best regards.

Comment: If you're building with vue cli and webpack, it should be hashing your output so that users will get the new version when they refresh the page or visit the site again. I haven't used AWS before, so could that be caching the old versions for users?

Comment: It seems that my webpack configuration don't hash my output. My files has the same name after building

Comment: If you run `vue create` and then `npm run build` on the newly created app it should already be setup to hash the built `js` and `css` files like `app.3b6dbb13.js`. How did you create your app and did you change anything?

Comment: I created it with `vue create` and my files are hashed. But if I create a new build, the hash is the same... Do I have to increase some version number or anything? I also tried to generate a config and set `filenameHashing` to true, which it should be by default, and nothing happend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it helps somebody.

I figured out some things. First there seems to be a problem with the cli, after some time the file hashing worked again (maybe a update or just a simple clean install). Second, I'am using `aws cloudfront` to provide my application, cloudfront caches your site on its endpoints. So I have to invalidate my cloudfront using

```
aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id YOUR_DISTRIBUTION_ID --paths '/*' --profile YOUR_PROFILE >/dev/null
```

So everybody got the new page after refreshing.